# Associate tables in Entity Framework without foreign key

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Is there a way I can associate two entities in EF if I don't have an explicit foreign key? I have a `relationtype` column and a `relationId`, where the `relationId` is the foreign key to 1 of 2 tables (determined by `relationtype`). If possible I would like to relate these objects in code, insert the top level entity and have the member populate this `relationid`.

Comment: *where the relationId is the foreign key to 1 of 2 tables (determined by relationtype)* - that's a horribly flawed database design to begin with ....

Comment: If you need this kind of relations go for NoSQL.